# href static files Django STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS

Tags: python, html, django

My settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my html page is href to my files using

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/default.css">
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/pythonlogo.jpeg">
```

I also tried:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/default.css' %}">
<img src="{% static 'images/pythonlogo.jpeg' %}">
```

The error I am getting in developer tools is

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/default.css 404 (NOT FOUND) 
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/pythonlogo.jpeg 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

I tried to print the path on to the web page by simply placing `{{STATIC_URL}}` on the page and  `/static/` appears.

My project directory path is:

```
django_test/
    admin/
    article/          <-- app
        templates/
    django_test/
        templates/
    static/
        css/
        images/
```

Comment: can you try with this `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: @Vahidabdi does not work. it actually ruined my logic a bit but nice try!

Comment: comment `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` and add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` to the `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: What server do you use as front-end? Apache/nginx/gunicorn/etc

Comment: Usually the built-in static handler expects app_name/`static`/‌app_name type of path, for [namespacing reasons](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) (search for 'namespacing' on the page). Try that.

Comment: @J0HN manage.py runserver

Comment: Are you intended to use django debug server in production? :)

Answer (score 2):

`STATIC_ROOT` is directory where all your static files will be copied by `collectstatic` command.
You should specify your path to `STATICFILES_DIRS` tuple to use it with built in webserver.

Comment: how would I use the static_root in my staticfiles_dirs? `STATICFILES_DIR = (('assets', STATIC_ROOT))`? Not quite sure how I would href that =/

Comment: You don't need `STATIC_ROOT` while you are using built in webserver. Put `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)` to your settings. Read this post http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/06/25/django-and-static-files/ to clearly understand how django works with static files.